# How to fit two arrays containing csr_matrixs' and labels respectively?

Tags: scipy, ipython, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, scikits

I am trying to store individual feature vector (ie X_train[i]) into an array X
and its corresponding label in another array Y.
When I try to fit these two arrays,I get the error
**ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**
How to fix this error.
Thanks in advance.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file                                           
pathToTrainData="/Users/rkasat/Documents/final year project/scripts/Drydata/leaf/train_backup.txt"

X_train,Y_train= load_svmlight_file(pathToTrainData);
X= []    
y=[]
for i in range(5):
    X.append(X_train[i])
    y.append(Y_train[i])

print(type(X[0]),type(y[0]))
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X,y)

output:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-cd4b481af30a> in <module>()
      8 from sklearn import svm
      9 clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
---> 10 clf.fit(X,y)

/Users/rkasat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    137                              "by not using the ``sparse`` parameter")
    138 
--> 139         X = atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype=np.float64, order='C')
    140         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    141 

/Users/rkasat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite)
    132     """
    133     return _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse.csr_matrix,
--> 134                                 "tocsr", force_all_finite)
    135 
    136 

/Users/rkasat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse_class, convmethod, force_all_finite)
    109     else:
    110         X = array2d(X, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy,
--> 111                     force_all_finite=force_all_finite)
    112         if force_all_finite:
    113             _assert_all_finite(X)

/Users/rkasat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in array2d(X, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite)
     89         raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data '
     90                         'is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to dense.')
---> 91     X_2d = np.asarray(np.atleast_2d(X), dtype=dtype, order=order)
     92     if force_all_finite:
     93         _assert_all_finite(X_2d)

/Users/rkasat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    318 
    319     """
--> 320     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    321 
    322 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

(<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are asking the same question three times? As people previously commented, you will get much more reliable answers if you actually show us your data as well as your code so we can debug it.

Comment: i am working on large scale hierarchichal text classification http://lshtc.iit.demokritos.gr/node/1. I want to do prediction of label of the feature vector at multiple levels.So ,all the feature vector which are classified same at level1 are put in  one single bucket.Similarly ,Different vectors are put in different buckets.Once I have buckets,I ll do my training and testing on each of the individual buckets at level2.I ll continue this process till I reach the leaf level and predict the actual label.

Comment: The code has become so complicated thats why i was reluctant to share it.It would further deviate from actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you don't have to use the for loop in your code. The following code might do what you want to do:

```
X_train, Y_train = load_svmlight_file(pathToTrainData);

from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X[:5, :],y[:5])
```

Answer (score 1):

@tanemaki is right, but it is worth explaining why this resolves the problem. `X_train` is (most likely) a `numpy` array. Slicing that with an integer (`X_train[i]`) returns the entire `i`-th row. `X` ends up being a list of numpy arrays. The `fit` method expects a single matrix. If you want to train on only the first 5 rows, you should slice as @tanemaki already demonstrated: `X[:5, :]` and `y[:5, :]`

Comment: can you please tell me if I want to train on selected rows only(say row 1 ,row 3 row6 and row7) and not just the first 5 rows,In that case,How should i proceed?

Comment: You should do `X[[1,3,6,7], :]`. The first argument to the slice (`[1,3,6,7`) specifies which rows you want to use, and the second specifies what columns you want. `:` means all rows/columns. `:10` and `10:` mean up to position 10 and from position 10 onwards respectively.